# Passing array string into function pointer?

Tags: c

I guess something is fundamentally wrong, I would like to send this global :

```
static char content[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
```

as an argument to a function pointer , where the function pointer def :

```
void(*flashReadDelegate)(char*[])=0;
```

and calling it with :

```
//save some data in (which prints ok)
strcpy(content[record_desc.record_id],toSave);

// ***Send the delegate out
(*flashReadDelegate)(content);  // ** here there is a compiler warnning about the argument
```

So how should the pointer argument look like if I want to send `content` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void(*flashReadDelegate)(char*[])=0;` is wrong. Your function pointer should be like this

```
void (*flashReadDelegate)(char (*)[MAX_WORD_LEN]);
```

You have not mentioned the prototype of the function to which `flashReadDelegate` is pointing. I am assuming that it's prototype would be

```
void func(char (*)[MAX_WORD_LEN]);
```

Now, in the function call `(*flashReadDelegate)(content);`, the argument array `content` will be converted to a pointer to an array of `MAX_WORD_LEN` `char`s (`(*)[MAX_WORD_LEN]`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! So why is my arg wrong? Isn't it a pointer to strings?

Comment: @Curnelious; As a function parameter `char*[]` is equivalent to `char**`.

Comment: Well `char*[]` reduces to pointer to the 1st element of an array of characters where as `char (*)[MAX_WORD_LEN]` reduces to a pointer to an array of characters with each array element being MAX_WORD_LEN characters wide

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `content` is not a **pointer to strings**. It is an **array of MAX_NUM_WORDS strings of MAX_WORD_LEN characters**.

If you want an **array of strings** you would need to declare `content` as: static char* content[MAX_NUM_WORDS];`